# how to convert an int to a bitmask?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to convert an int to a bitmask?

example:

```
int i = 33;
```

should be converted to (not sure of the datatype)

```
bool[] bitmask = new[] {true, false, false, false, false, true};
```

**Update**
In reaction to most answers:

I need to do this:

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(showGroup.Value));
List<String> showStrings = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i++)
{
    if(bits[i])
        showStrings.Add((i+1).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
}
```

How would that go without converting it to a bitarray?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An `int` already is a bitmask. If you want to twiddle the bits, you can use bitwise operators freely on ints. If you want to convert the `int` to an enum that has the `Flags` attribute, a simple cast will suffice.

Comment: And if you need to access the ith bit (with i being 0-indexed), use `1 << i`.

Answer (score 13):

Found it

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(System.BitConverter.GetBytes(showGroup.Value));
```

Comment: You'll probably find that the in method that @JS Bangs suggested will be much quicker.

Comment: Well, it's such a tiny conversion, it will hardly matter. But for the sake of correctness I would love to learn :)

Comment: There is an example on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute

Comment: Thanks. [more characters to please the SO overlord]

Answer (score 5):

You could construct a `bool[32]` and loop through all bits in the `int`, masking it with 2^(loop counter) and setting the `bool`s in the array appropriately.

Are you sure you need this, though?  Most operations with bitmasks work with ints directly.

To answer the question in your edit:

```
int val = 35;
List<string> showStrings = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    if (( (1 << i) & val) > 0)
    {
        showStrings.Add((i + 1).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
    }
}
```

prints:

```
01  
02  
06
```

Not the most obvious solution if you're not used to bit arithmetic, true.  Mask each bit in the integer value with 2^(bit-index), and if the resulting value is greater than zero (indicating that the bit at that index is set), do something.  `1 << i` (left-shifting) is equivalent to `2^i`, and may have the same performance characteristics once JITted, but I'm used to this form.

Expressed as a macro-like method:

```
bool IsSet(int val, int index)
{
    return (( (1 << (index-1)) & val) > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int val = 33;
var bitarray = new BitArray(new[] { val });
var att = bitarray.Cast<bool>().ToArray();
```

Comment: I like this. For those interested, the Cast method is an Extension Method and requires "using System.Linq" declaration which under Mono requires a reference to System.Core

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked, here is a solution without using BitArray:

```
// First define a bitmask enum for the bits you are interested in
[Flags]
public enum BitFlags
{
  Flag1 = 1,
  Flag2 = 2,
  Flag3 = 4,
  Flag4 = 8,
  Flag5 = 16
  // ...
}

int index = 0;
List<string> showStrings = new List<string>();
foreach(int flag in Enum.GetValues(typeof(BitFlags))cast<int>())
{
  index += 1;
  if ((input & flag) == flag)
    showStrings.Add(index.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
}
```

It is about the same amount of code, with negligible performance difference.  It does however let you strongly define your bit values and you can choose to omit bits in the BitFlags enum that you don't care about.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know this was possible. Another tool in my belt :)